# Почему typeof пропускает функцию в цикле for in?

Tags: javascript

```
AbstractProduct.prototype.getFullInformation = function() {
    var str = "";
    for (var key in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof (key) !== "function"){
          console.log(typeof key);
            str += " " + key + ":" + this[key] + " \n";
        }
    }
    return str;
};


function Clothes(param) {
    this.ID = param.ID;
    this.name = param.name; 
    this.description = param.descrip; 
    this.price = param.price;
    this.images = param.images;
    this.reviews = param.reviews;
    this.bla = function() {
      return "tratata";
    }
}
```

Есть метод который перебирает объект и записывает только свои свойства, без методов. Но проверка typeof на функцию не работает, и метод тоже записывается. Почему? И как это исправить ?

console.log( lunar.getFullInformation() );
вывод должен быть вот такой, только без метода в конце, только свойства.

```
ID:15 
 name:pants 
 description:bla bla 
 price:201.5 
 images:image1,image2 
 material:poliester 
 color:navy 
 brand:puma 
 sizes:XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL 
 activeSize:S 
 quantity:5 
 date:Sun Feb 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Финляндия (зима)) 
 reviews:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
 bla:function () {
        console.log("Sda");
    }
```

Comment: key - это всегда строка

Comment: Добавь пример того, как ты хочешь вызывать эту функцию, и что хочешь получить на выходе

Comment: @andreymal, напиши ответ :-)

Comment: @andreymal есть идеи как это исправить ?

Comment: @YURII, просто проверяй не тип **ключа**, а тип **значения по этому ключу**

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, заработало )

Comment: напишешь ответ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указано в [описании](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (variable in object) { ...
}
```

`variable` - различные *имена свойств* присваиваемые переменной на каждой итерации.

Имена свойств - это строки, таким образом, тип переменной `key` в вопросе **всегда** "string".

Так как нужно проверить тип *свойства*, сначала его нужно получить по указанному ключу `key` и только потом проверять.

```
for (var key in this) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof (this[key]) !== "function"){
        str += " " + key + ":" + this[key] + " \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и при `typeof` достаточно `!=`

Comment: @Regent, в данном случае без разницы вообще :)

Comment: Целый же лишний символ печатать :)